# ConnectionID is in incorrect formate. SignalR

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, signalr

I use`signalR` latest library. I downloaded `signalR` library from gitHub [SignalR gitHub link](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) and installed pod file in my app. I am working on iOS end. I don't know about asp.net. The only url is provided to me for integration. Here is my code

```
__weak SRConnection *connection = [SRConnection connectionWithURL:SIGNALR_PATH];

[connection addValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kAccessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"MyAuthentication"];

connection.received = ^(NSString * data) {
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
};
connection.started =  ^{
    [connection send:@"hello world"];
};

[connection start];
```

Connection open successfully but When I get try to send message it gives me an error "The ConnectionId is in incorrect format".

I am using latest library of signalR. I don't know what I need to authorised. Is only url enough for that? Or will need to add accessToken that I get on login?.

Please help me what I need for integrating signalR. I searched a lot but couldn't find any clear information.

Comment: What are you using as a backend? Where is the server running?

Comment: I don't know about that. Client provided me only url. Is it server error?

Comment: Are you positive that server and client versions are compatible?

Comment: i have implemented SignalR. please first confirm from client how many arguments you need in your URL. because whenever we have to send some message to server we need some argument to follow. first try this.